# How to set pointer-events style on custom FrameworkElement

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, uno-platform

I'm trying to create a file dialog in a WebAssembly application built with Uno. I've added a custom FrameworkElement to create `<input type="file">` in the page like so:

```
[HtmlElementAttribute("input")]
public sealed partial class PicInputControl : FrameworkElement
{
    public PicInputControl()
    {
      this.SetHtmlAttribute("type", "file");
      this.SetHtmlAttribute("accept", "image/png, image/jpg, image/bmp, image/jpeg");
      this.ClearCssStyle("pointer-events");
    }
}
```

When the application runs, the css style option `pointer-events` is set to `none` by default, even when clearing the `pointer-events` style. This needs to be `auto` in order to be able to interact with the ui element with the mouse to click it.

How should I go about setting the pointer-events on this control?

Comment: Did you ever get this fully implemented? I’m trying to do this now but not sure what to do after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pointer-events` CSS style is [overridden by the Uno framework](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/769b8e816c4435b46da0f20e1de34f1e5216cb02/src/Uno.UI/UI/Xaml/UIElement.Pointers.wasm.cs#L335) at runtime based on the WinUI rules for hit testing, so changing it from the ctor won't have any effect.

To have it set to `auto`, you need to ensure that your custom element qualifies as 'hit visible'. An easy way to do that is to set a non-null `Background` value.

```cs
    [HtmlElementAttribute("input")]
    public sealed partial class PicInputControl : FrameworkElement
    {
        public PicInputControl()
        {
            this.SetHtmlAttribute("type", "file");
            this.SetHtmlAttribute("accept", "image/png, image/jpg, image/bmp, image/jpeg");
            this.ClearCssStyle("pointer-events");
            Background = SolidColorBrushHelper.Transparent;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly. Thank you very much!